# How to upgrade PostgreSQL from version 8.4 to 9.4?

Tags: postgresql, upgrade, postgresql-9.4, postgresql-8.4, centos

I want to upgrade my PostgreSQL from version **8.4** to **9.4**.

The [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/upgrading.html) is not very clear to me.

1. Will I lose my old databases if I do the upgrade?
2. How can I backup my old databases if I am to lose them after the upgrade?
3. How can I upgrade my psql?

My PostgreSQL is running on a [**CentOS 6.6**](https://www.centos.org/) server.

Comment: To be honest, the description is _very_ clear on the linked page.  Taking a dump means you have a dump for the case something does not work.  That also means that you don't lose it.  Furthermore, there is a link on that page pointing to how to actually install a newer version - for example, on Ubuntu, there is a `postgresql-client-9.4` package that contains `psql`.

Comment: @dezso So if I uninstall psql 8.4 and go for 9.4, I will lose my old databases?

Comment: If you take a dump of them, then no.  You should anyway have regular backups that you test for recoverability, so this should be no issue at all.  Also, if you choose to use `pg_upgrade`, it will keep your DBs - but taking a backup is a must in this case, too.

Comment: "`How can I backup my old databases if`" - there is no *if*. Your databases will almost certainly be perfectly fine after the upgrade but you should *always* have fresh (preferably tested) backups when performing an operation like this anyway in case of unexpected problems (assume the worst: a power cut or other hardware fault part way might leave you in a position that is difficult to roll either back or forward from). Depending on your regular backup plan you might not need to take extra backups.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This is how I solved my problem.

**Upgrade Postgresql 8.4 to 9.4 in Centos**

```
 1. Yum Install PG9.4
 2. wget http://yum.postgresql.org/9.4/redhat/rhel-6-x86_64/pgdg-redhat94-9.4-1.noarch.rpm
 3. yum install pgdg-redhat94-9.4-1.noarch.rpm
 4. yum install postgresql94-server
 5. service postgresql-9.4 initdb
 6. chkconfig postgresql-9.4 on
```

**Backup Data**

```
 7. su - postgres

 8. pg_dumpall > dump.sql
```

**Restore Data**

```
 9. service postgresql stop

 10. service postgresql-9.4 start

 11. su - postgres

 12. psql < dump.sql
```

**Config Network Access**

`vi /var/lib/pgsql/9.4/data/postgresql.conf`

```
 1. listen_addresses = '*'
 2. port = 5432
```

`/var/lib/pgsql/9.4/data/pg_hba.conf`

```
# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all         all                               ident
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all         all         127.0.0.1/32          ident
host    all         all         130.51.79.0/24        md5
host    all         all         10.210.29.0/24        md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all         all         ::1/128               ident
```

**Remove PG8.4**

```
 1. yum remove postgresql
 2. ln -s /usr/pgsql-9.4/bin/psql /usr/local/bin/psql
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you rejected my edit as "harm readability". It actually makes the commands easier to copy,

Comment: I just did an upgrade from 9.2 to 9.6 using this method, and it worked. Thanks !

Comment: I think it is impossible to use pgdump to migrate a database with terabytes of data for example. Is there another way to do that?

Comment: FOr the first command, "Yum Install PG9.4", is that tthe right capitalization for everything?

Comment: @deFreitas I'm a bit late but you can use `pg_upgrade` if upgrading from >=8.4 and if you use the same server. `pg_upgrade` is usefull in this cases and really faster: on Ubuntu 18 it took me less time making a `pg_upgrade` than a `pg_dump` to restore a 1GB database. The con is that you have to install and run 2 postgres versions in the same machine (listening to different ports, of course).

Comment: After upgrading to postgres 12, the original postgres moved the unix socket to /tmp. Surprise! I had to add `unix_socket_directory = '/var/run/postgresql'` to the postgresql.conf file to get it back.

Answer (score 3):

`service postgresql-9.4` initdb didn't work for me, I had to use `sudo /usr/pgsql-9.4/bin/postgresql94-setup initdb` (found [here](https://github.com/hw-cookbooks/postgresql/issues/186)).

Thanks for the great instructions, I was able to update from 9.2 to 9.4 without any issues, even though I had to reconfigure my `pg_hba.conf` file, that was trivial.

Answer (score 1):

Better than linking a single postgresql94 psql binary to /usr/(local/)bin is to use the alternatives system:

```
cd /etc/alternatives/
ls pgsql-* -1 | xargs -L 1 alternatives --auto
```

Which creates links of binaries, mans, confs, ... of postgresql94 to default directories for CentOS.